# How to define a function `deriv[f[x]]` such that its output is an unevaluated expression `fx=D[f[x],x]`?

Tags: function-construction, string-manipulation

I want to define a function `deriv[f_[x_]]` such that when I run `deriv[f[x]]`, the output is an unevaluated expression `fx=D[f[x],x]`.

The following does not work

```
deriv[f_[x_]] := ToExpression[ToString[f] <> ToString[x] <> "=" <> ToString[D[f[x], x]]]
```

because the output of `deriv[f[x]]` is just `D[f[x],x]`, not `fx=D[f[x],x]`.

Comment: `=` is an infix alias for `Set`, so when you force your string with `ToExpression` MMA will then evaluate that expression automatically as it does with all expressions that are not held or in `Unevaluated`. So really you're getting the output of `Set` and that's why it's only the RHS of your argument. Try wrapping the downvalue in `Unevaluated`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `deriv[f_[x_]] := HoldForm[Set[fx, D[f[x], x]]]`?

Comment: @hYPotenuser, `Defer[]` might actually make more sense here; on the other hand, if the input is `g[z]`, I suppose the expected output is `gz = …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
deriv[f_[x_]] := 
 Inactivate[
  ToExpression@StringJoin[ToString[f], ToString[x]] = D[f[x], x], 
  Set | D]
```

Then:

```
deriv[kr[x]]
```

outputs

```
Inactive[Set][kryx, Inactive[D][kr[yx], yx]]
```

which displays as

```
kryx = D[kr[yx], yx]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
deriv[f_[x_]] := Inactive[D][f[x], x]
```

Then:

[image]